# submit button works only on 2nd click after onchange called on input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

i have input text field where user can provide some details and on change of text field, ajax function is called to save a data. when user writes something in text field and click on submit button, it calls the ajax function but form is not submitted at the same time. it gets submitted after second click.
i want if user provides some inputs and click on form submit, ajax should get triggered first and after that form should get submitted without need of one more click.below is sample code:

```
<form:form name ="samplename" action="submitAction">
<form:textarea id="testID" onchange="ajaxmehtod()"></form:textarea>
<input type="button" value="submit">
</form:form>
```

Comment: can you share your jQuery?

Comment: can you provide the ajaxmehtod function?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a regular button with an "onclick" method (e.g. submitForm()), instead of the input type button submit. Also remove the "onchange" method on the textarea.

Then when clicking on the button, check in javascript if the textarea contains any data, then execute the ajaxmethod() and when the ajax is ready, trigger the form submit using $('#samplename').submit();

```
<form id="sampleName" name ="sampleName" action="">
   <textarea id="testID" name="textAreaName"></textarea>       
</form>

<button onclick="submitForm()"></button>
```

In javascript:

```
  function submitForm(){
    //Check textarea contains data
    ....

   // Execute ajax method
    ajaxMethod();

   // If ajax method is done, submit form
   $('#sampleName').submit();          
  }
```

Something like that?

You can also prevent the default submit action, more info : https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: i want ajax function to be called on change of text field even if user does not click on submit. that is why onchange is written on textfield.

Comment: The onchange is only triggered when the textarea loses focus (blurs and something was changed). So if you click outside of the textarea, only then it will trigger the ajaxmethod. What you could try is use the " keydown" event together with a timeout. So if a user enters some text, and a specified amount of time passes, then a specified function gets executed.

In the ajaxmethod you could manually trigger the form submit as mentioned above.

Comment: on change event is getting triggered when text area is loosing focus and when user clicks on submit after writing data in text area it triggers onchange but action written for submit functionality is not getting triggered. how both these events can be triggered at same time?

Comment: I would recommend creating a new function which is then called within the onchange (textarea) and/ or the onclick (submit button). In both cases (click and change), that function would be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try input type submit instead of button

```
<form id="sampleName" name ="sampleName" action="" onsubmit="ajaxmehtod()">
   <textarea id="testID" name="textAreaName"></textarea>   
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

this will submit your form onsubmit and it u need it onblur of textarea u can add

`<textarea id="testID" name="textAreaName" onblur="somefunction()"></textarea>`

Comment: i tried using "submit" instead of button as well as blur event , but both did not work for me. please suggest if anything else can be tried